# Struts: Accessing bean attributes from View

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read!

I'm working on a web application on the NetBeans IDE 7.1, with Struts 1.3.10, Apache Tomcat 7.0.22, PostgreSQL 9.1 on Windows 7.

My question is the following:

I have a class called "Reminder", it's properties are: startDate, endDate and id. I want to get all the start and end dates from all the reminders in my jsp so I can highlight this range of days on a calendar at a sidebar of my web application.

In my login action I have the following code:

```
Reminder reminder = new Reminder();
ArrayList<Reminder> queryResults = 
dbms.queryReminders(reminder);
```

Here I've gathered all the reminders from the database (The model function simply does a SELECT * from reminders and returns that)

Then I finish with:

```
request.setAttribute("reminders",queryResults);
return mapping.findForward(User);
```

Here I've set the collected results to an attribute I decided to call "reminders", this should have all the reminders I want.

Afterwards I get the data from view like this:

```
<bean:write name="reminders" scope="request"/>
```

But all I get is something like: [classes.Reminder@1d1ce11] (In this case, I have only inserted one reminder in the database. Also I have a class called Reminder in my package called classes, so I think it's referring to an object of class Reminder (the one I inserted on the DB)).

But what I want to do is to be able to obtain the startDate and endDate from that object, not just the object like that. Does anybody know how to access these properties from the jsp?

I've done a lot of research but usually what tutorials show you is a way to get the properties of classes with these bean tags, but here I have an array of objects of a certain class and I want their properties, so things are different.

I would really appreciate some guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you stored a `List` (of type `ArrayList`) to the request on the following code:

```
request.setAttribute("reminders",queryResults);
```

So, in order to get each `Reminder` from the `List`, you will need to iterate through the list (in the JSP).

To iterate through a collection, you will use [`<logic:iterate>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.0.2/struts-logic.html) tag:

```
<logic:iterate name="reminders" id="reminder" scope="request">
    ID: <bean:write name="reminder" property="id" />
    Start Date: <bean:write name="reminder" property="startDate" />
    End Date: <bean:write name="reminder" property="endDate" />
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help. :-)